# Don't show incoming mail notification for filtered emails in Thunderbird

Tags: windows, thunderbird, notifications

I use filters to redirect some emails to separate folders, different from my Inbox.

Currently, Thunderbird shows a notification for any email message I receive:

[image: Thunderbird notification]

I want it to show only notifications about emails that go to my Inbox, but not about those that get filtered to the other folders.

Is there any way I can do that?